# android: how to play sound in android on button click from a separate class

Tags: java, android, media-player

I'am a newbie in java and android and i want to play sound in my app on different button clicks, for this purpose I made a separate class for playing sound but could not make it work.I want to call this class and play sound when user clicks on the button. Can anyone help how to make a separate class for media player and call it from a click of a button.

code of the class where i declare the media player

```
public class CorrectSound extends Activity implements OnPreparedListener{

  public static void playSound(Context context){
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.tiktik);
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(null);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      mp.start();
  }
}
```

this is the button which is in separate activity i want to call this class here.

```
public void optionAClick (View V){
    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this,profile.class);
    startActivity(i);   
}
```

Comment: Try to define sound play generalize code in parent activity and just try to play sound on child activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, delete all in the playSound function, and put this:

```
public static void playSound(Context context){
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.tiktik);
    mp.start();
}
```

Now, whenever you call your function, it will make a sound.

Comment: Thank you so much. could you please show me call onPrepared() in this method, without calling onPrepared() sound does not play.

Comment: I dont know about that, but you can set onPreparedListener,there, you can overide onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) and just put mp.start();

Comment: calling this method is the big issue. you mean to say overiding in this on button click.?

Comment: No, in your function, you delete mp.start(), and write next mp.setOnPreapredListener(new OnPreparedListener)...and onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) you put mp.start(); Understand?

Comment: ok. please see my post i added the method which you gave. but still sound not playing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87761/discussion-between-anita-and-vulovic-vukasin).

Answer (score 0):

Make a static function in a class and just call it from any class you want.

**Example**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    ......
    ......

    public static PlaySound(Context context){   
       MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.notif);
       mp.start();
    }    
}
```

**From some other class**

Just use this:

```
MyApplication.PlaySound(this);
```